Android Studio - Timeout error xml preview
The preview took too long to load. The issue can be caused by long operations or infinite loops on the Preview code. If you think this issue is not caused by your code, you can report a bug in our issue tracker
Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 Patch 1
Build #AI-241.19072.14.2412.12360217, built on September 12, 2024

After updating the latest Android studio, the issue is resolved.
Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1
Build #AI-242.21829.142.2421.12409432, built on September 25, 2024
